# Fast algorithm for detecting an object in an image

Tags: image, opencv, homography

I'm working on a small program for optical mark recognition.
The processing of the scanned form consists of two steps:
1) Find the form in the scanned image, descew and crop borders.
2) With this "normalized" form, I can simply search the marks by using coordinates from the original document and so on.

For the first step, I'm currently using the Homography functions from OpenCV and a perspecive transform to map the points. I also tried the SurfDetector.

However, both algorithms are quite slow and do not really meet the speed requierements when scanning forms from a document scanner.

Can anyone point me to an alternative algorithm/solution for this specific problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Viola-Jones cascade classifier is pretty quick. It is used in OpenCV for Face detection, but you can train it for different purpose. Depending on the appearance of what you call your "form", you can use simpler algorithms such as cross correlation as said by Muffo.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In that case I would have a training process for every form. And building a positive/negative list for complex forms? I've tried this with some sample implementations without success. Moreover, the estimated bounding box is not very precise as a basis for deskewing.

Answer (score 0):

Try with ORB or FAST detector: they should be faster than SURF ([documentation here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/feature_detection_and_description.html)).

If those don't match your speed requirement you should probably use a different approach. Do you need scale and rotation invariance? If not, you could try with the cross correlation.

Comment: I've just tried ORB and FAST, however, they are just a litte faster on this task, no big difference. Scale and rotation invariance is necessesary for the accuracy in step two. Additionally it is necessary to not only rotate the image but also deskew it since some document scanners produce a slightly skewed scan.